# How did an IP send Get requests to my code?

Tags: security, webserver, ip-address

I am new to web development. I am developing a flask web server on my linode linux web server on port 5000. I got this output from an unknown ip. I researched the ip and found out that this is a whitelisted IP address and is "harmless", but I dont know. It looks like it sent GET requests to my cover photo, the javascript, the css, an icon on the page, and an unknown request. What does sending a GET request to these items even entail? I dont have any button or anything that sends a get request to these items. Whenever I am developing the web server while on port 5000 I am usually the only IP on the output. Additionally, this web server communicates with a raspberry pi over mqtt over the non-encrypted port 1883.

Again, I am new to this world and am wondering if anyone can help me decipher what this means that would be very helpful. In the meantime should I will configure the servers firewall to only allow requests from my computers ip to my server? Anyone think this is a reasonable next step or have any additional advice?

[image: server output]

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what's happening is that your website is sending a GET request to retrieve those assets (e.g. your images) which are stored under your localhost address and the paths that you see in the console output.

Comment: At least one of the IPs is owned by Facebook, so it is highly unlikely that the requests are coming from the OP's website.

Comment: This is so odd to me. Do individual hackers use facebook IP's to scrape the web and collect these resources? Or do people use these resources as ways to hack into my network or something?

Comment: @MikeSandstrom This completely looks like port 5000 is open to the world.  This surprises me on a fresh server.  AWS's policy for example is block ALL ports by default, then you open them via security groups.  I'm not so familiar with Linode, but it sounds like they require you to specifically block your ports (ewww).  Definately worth checking: [configure-a-firewall](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server/#configure-a-firewall).

Comment: Yea its open to all devices on port 5000. i need to adjust that becuase Im sure that was a bot or something